# My Django app is not serving static files

Tags: python, django

This is quite strange. It was working OK, but the machine it was running broke and I had to mount it again without success. The webapp shows with wuite background, without images, css nor js loaded.

This is how the app is structured:
[image: App folder structure]

These are the variables in settings.py which matter (please ask for any other if required):

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/var/www/myapp/static/',
)
```

And into my tempaltes, I always set the contents' URL like this:

```
<img id="logo" src="{{STATIC_URL}}images/logo.png"\>
```

Any idea about where the problem is?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/?

Comment: have you checked your webserver logs?

Comment: @jonrsharpe In fact I did. Nevertheless it did not help (I'm using {{STATIC_URL}} at src field in the templates instead of {% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %} as in that docs chapter, but I kept if because it was working like this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the error: Apache was running as default and serving the html templates in port 80, but without permissions for the static files.

Answer (score 1):

The settings you have are generally discouraged, for local development they will work fine, however if you were to attempt to run that on a Linux based machine, it wouldn't work.

Here's how it should be formatted:

[image]

Here are the settings that would make it like that:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')
#this applies to all operating systems
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
)
```

You would put your static folders and files in "static_dirs", and then whenever you needed to sync to "static_root". You would type: "python manage.py collectstatic".

In your template file you would then type:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<img id="logo" src="{% static "images/logo.png" %}"\>
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

check if the source is loaded using view source and if yes from there check if any link to your static assets are accessible if present then you have to hard refresh the browser

Comment: I'm using Control+F5 (windows) to hard refresh the browser. Still the same. I check the url of the images and if I visit e.g. localhost:8080/static/images/logo.png, the 404 Django error template appears

Comment: try printing {{ STATIC_URL }} in one of your templates and check its value

Comment: It just says '/static/'

Comment: may be the path is not getting right in 
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static'),
) , try this

Comment: I don't have BASE_DIR declared. Anyway I tried something similar with os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__ file __), '..', 'static').replace('\\','/') without success

Answer (score 0):

Include     `{% load staticfiles %}`     in template.

Comment: Why like that and not like I'm doing? Is this something it has changed for a newer Django version? (As I said, the app was working OK, that's why I didn't touch the templates)

Comment: It doesn't. Even also loading images like <img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>

Comment: Try checking [link](http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/my_app/myexample.jpg) . Can you see the image there?

Comment: Ok this is strange: it does work locally if I use an url like the one you gave me with 127.0.0.1 or localhost. But if I run the app for outside my network with runserver 0.0.0.0 (yeah, I know it's not the most secure play), it doesn't. Any idea?

Comment: What source/error are you seeing in the case you didn't see image? -> Inspect Element

Comment: No source error. The images, css and js are just not rendered. If I inspect the image with inspect element in Firefox, it just says "Unable to load the image" (or similar, I'm translating from my spanish Firefox)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88191/discussion-between-raju-dawadi-and-roman-rdgz).

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. If you get any more relevant information from your chat, please add it here too.

Answer (score 0):

You comment in reply to the post by Allen Fernandes above indicates you are in DEBUG mode. Is `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: `from django.conf import settings` is in your settings.py too?

Comment: No, settings is not being imported, but do I really need to import settings inside settings.py? That is not included in the default settings.py file

Comment: Sorry, ignore this. If you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` which you do, you don't need this. Taken from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development